# Closing fancybox and adding class to an item in parent in jquery

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Basically have a page which launches a modal (fancybox), then a button in the modal window which needs to close the modal and then add a class to an element on the page that's beneath the modal.

I've been doing this inline for various reasons (the setup is a little confusing), the code I have on the  is this:

```
onclick='$.fancybox.close(); parent($('#message-whitepaper').addClass('active'));'
```

I think I must have the parent part incorrect or something, have tried various combinations with no luck, if anyone can point out what i've done wrong that'd be great.

Thanks!

Comment: When you initiate facnybox use it afterClose callback. Something like: `$(".fancybox").fancybox({
           afterClose : function(){
             $('#message-whitepaper').addClass('active')
           }
        }); `

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that will add the class to all buttons that close the modal, there is a specific button in the modal that we need to apply this to

Comment: Then you can do `onclick='$.fancybox.close(); $('#message-whitepaper').addClass('active');'` simple just remove `parent()`

Comment: Could you show your HTML code, the button and its parent? Also, could you clarify if you want to add the class to the element `#message-whitepaper` ? or to the button that triggered fancybox? ... your question and comment contradict themselves a little bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think Different answered above:

> Then you can do
>
> ```
> onclick='$.fancybox.close(); 
> $('#message-whitepaper').addClass('active');
> ```
>
> simple just remove `parent()`
>   Think Different Jan 16 at 13:00